# Random 5 alpha character path appended to requests

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, ssl, nginx

Starting in early September (maybe) our customers (thousands across the US) started experiencing "random" 5 character alpha paths being appended to their URL requests with 302 responses intermittently when requesting the root of their domains. We have been exploring all possibilities, including malware, updates to hardware and software, and have not been able to find the cause.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, and found the cause?

Happy to provide more details of the environments as needed. Some details may have to be provided via PM.

### **Sample Paths**

```
domain.com/OUZPZ/
domain2.com/LVQgZ/
domain2.com/UpTZZ/
domain2.com/WNZOR/
domain3.com/UncLZ/
domain4.com/SVpjZ/
domain4.com/WOVRZ/
domain5.com/NcmUZ/
```

### **Curl Path**

```
curl -IL domain.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /WQiNZ/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /ToNLZ/WQiNZ/

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
cache-control: no-cache
Location: /WQiNZ/
```

### **General Notes**

- **We only see this happen in person on sites with SSL enabled.**
- Wordpress multisite installs.
- GoDaddy customers are experiencing this issue with their forwarding
  service as well (see links below).
- We only use GoDaddy as the domain registrar, and use an internal DNS name server system based on AWS route53.
- When we audit our server logs, we see many more URL paths of this
  type. They stretch all the way back to April of this year (2017), but most
  of them have a google bot user agent

  - Regex for search: `/\/[a-zA-Z]{5}\//`
- Both our company security team, hosting provider, and Sucuri have
  audited the environments and have not found any malware.
- Plugins audited for functionality and nothing found.
- Using Let's Encrypt SSL certs.
- Google and hosting provider say it does not have to do with DDoS
  protection in their environments (see reddit thread below).
- The only commonality so far between Godady and our environments are linux
  boxes.

### **Articles/Threads Related to Subject**

- https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/My-domain-name-not-resolving-correctly-6-random-characters-are/td-p/60782
- https://www.reddit.com/r/webhosting/comments/18v950/302_redirect_to_random_5_character_subdirectories/
- http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2015-December/049486.html
- https://www.drupal.org/node/848972
- [Junk characters in URL when domain forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46038158/junk-characters-in-url-when-domain-forwarding)
- http://gold-thiolate.com/2013/godaddy-random-302-redirect/

Comment: I had a similar [experience](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176454/site-receives-high-amount-of-random-requests). My site was DDoS attacked and maybe the Apache somehow produced these random calls, when it was under high load??

Comment: We actually never found the exact cause, but it was definitely due to the GoDaddy forwarding service. We had to put rewrite rules on our server side to detect requests like these and remove the appended string. From what I've read, this happens all the time with GoDaddy, and they've never found or fixed the cause. We are moving thousands of domains away from them due to the poor service from this issue and many others.

Comment: I get a lot of it now too. (The server load is low or normal.) Sometimes even two appended 5-character random strings. So far only in a GoDaddy "Linux Classic" hosting. Not in another cPanel server. I have to look into the rewrite rules. Random strings may be tricky? If you have any hints how to rewrite, please give :)

Comment: @ycc_swe This is the regex we have in place `^\/[A-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{3}[A-Z]{1}\/` we then send to the `/` root. This has worked well for us across thousands of sites, but we ran a script to make sure none of those sites used page paths that matched that. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thx. I have tried sending to the corrected url, but have failed so far. Finally tried to [rewrite](https://pastebin.com/vDc9m3CQ) to a [php-file](https://pastebin.com/mfBny9BE) that would exit to the corrected url. Also fails at present. [L] flag will still not stop another run of htaccess for the corrected url. Other problems w query strings may also arise. I think you are right. Send to root or other page and also give information to visitor on the 404-page. I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533267/removing-random-characters-from-end-of-url)