# Random chars appearing in Apache access logs

Tags: apache

We are seeing random letters appear in access logs. The requests 404 since the content does not exist. The requests are made by a variety of users and other requests from the same ip usually look genuine. There is no way to request these from the site. Some of these requests even appear from internal traffic on our network.

Example:

157.203.177.191 - - [04/Feb/2018:23:51:20 +0000] "GET /VLTRP/content/dam/example/dotcom/images/ABtest/existing-customer-thumb.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 60294 39082 "http://www.example.com/shop.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" 2

Without the /VLTRP this is a genuine request. Has anyone seen something similar before?
For info we are running Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) with ModSec enabled. We do see similar behaviour on another site where we do not have ModSec configured. We see similar requests for internal, external and bot traffic.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there any GoDaddy domain forwarding involved in your setup?

Comment: Nope, no GoDaddy domains referenced at all.

Comment: No solution, but you are at least not alone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307518/random-5-alpha-character-path-appended-to-requests

Comment: That is really interesting thank you, one suspicion I had was our ddos protection platform (we use Arbor) could be doing this but we are unsure how this works and if it is even capable of changing the requests in this way.